# How to organize myself around calculus?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, learning

Calculus is the most advanced topic I have encountered in math. The book that I am using is clear as can be, but it has so many definitions and theorems.

1. I would like to have all the most crucial definitions and theorems in note or list form so that I can review them efficiently. Should I make it by myself (write it down) or can I download it somewhere?
2. What is best practice for learning calculus? How should I know what is most crucial?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wrote a [summary](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By3lNuPto1AidFMxLUFzUzRnSkk/view?usp=sharing) of some of the key intuition (not rigor) behind calculus.  Feel free to contact me if you have any questions or suggestions.

Comment: Read it line by line. You can't know which are the 'more important things'!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculus is all about practise. If you have a book you're studying from, make summaries and do as many exercises as you can. You cannot read a Calculus book like a novel, but need to understand every concept before passing on to the next one, because it all builds up. Good luck